# Can I integrate with respect to this 'variable'?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

If I define $u = \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \sup_{m\geq k} \sup_{t} |f_k(t)-f_m(t)|$, and I get to

$u \leq g(u) $

for some integrable etc function $g$ can I then integrate both sides wrt $u$? Here $f_n:[0,a] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

To integrate wrt $u $, which means that $u $ is the integration variable, you should know in which interval .
it seems in your case that $u $ is a fixed real.
What is the definition domain of your integrable function $g $ .

Comment: Integrate between 0 and a say, where g is defined for all non negative arguments

Comment: @Rlanls But $u $ is not a variable.

Comment: oh okay that was my original question: does it make sense to integrate wrt u. Was thinking no but wanted confirmation, thanks.